# Identify when a user is using the skype web control - on botframework

Tags: botframework, skype, skype-bots

I'm looking for a way to identify whether a user is sending a message with the Skype web control and not through the standard client.
Is there any parameter attached to the `session` object or any other way to do so?
Or maybe a `ref` parameter like Facebook messenger has?

I would like to know also if the user is authenticated or not - I could see that the name is always `Guest` but it doesn't seem to be a very robust way to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect it via bot `receive` middleware event, e.g.

```
bot.use({
  receive: function (event, next) {
    // handle `event.entities` for your needs
    console.log(event.entities)
    next();
  },
});
```

the `event.entities` shoule be like:

```
 [ { locale: 'en-US',
       country: 'US',
       platform: 'Web',
       type: 'clientInfo' } ],
```

and for skype for web, the `platform` property is `Web`, for windows client, the `platform` property is `Windows`.

Comment: hey, I tested this solution but it seems like I'm not getting the `platform`. the output looks like this:
`0:Object {locale: "en-US", type: "clientInfo"}
locale:"en-US"
type:"clientInfo"`

Comment: @Amitbe, where and how you get these info?

Comment: I used the method you've provided `bot.use...`

Comment: @gary-liu-msft did you have a chance to check it?

Comment: @Amitbe, actually, I tested directly on Azure Bot Service, and leverage the online code Editor to check the outputs. Unfortunately, I  cannot reproduce your issue. Could you tell me how to reproduce your issue, maybe?

Comment: @gary-liu-msft well I just pasted the code to my bot, it uses libraries. does it have anything to with being authenticated or not?